# Monitoring IIS outbound concurrent HTTP request

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, iis, iis-8

I have a .net application that following an inbound request needs to make multiple subsequent outbound HTTP requests. During periods of high load an increase in response time occurs. This was having a serious detrimental effect on our application. Like many others before me we to counteracted this by increasing the maxConnection value from the default to the MS recommended value (12 * #CPU) which in our case is 96. This allows IIS to make upto 96 requests to a single address at any one time.

```
<system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address = "*" maxconnection = "96" />
        </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Thankfully our application is now responding well even under peak usage. What I would like to know now is considering previously we were hitting the limit of 2 concurrent requests per min. What tools/monitoring can I use to figure out how close we are to the new threshold of 96?

Comment: The setting is not for IIS. Anyway, you can leverage perfmon to monitor the connections.

Comment: Not for IIS? Snippet can be added to machine or web config - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821268/contention,-poor-performance,-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-services-from-an-asp.net-application Care to elaborate on which perfmon metric to use?

Comment: That setting is to control num of the connection your application can use. From the subject, I thought you meant to control the connection that IIS can use. So which scenario are you talking about?

Comment: @mattfei I have edited the question a little so hopefully it clarifies the issue. Previously limited on the number of outbound connections, we changed the maxConnection value and are no longer suffering. What I would like to know is as my last question states, how close are we to the new threshold?

Comment: Then try the perf counters mentioned on this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70xadeyt(v=vs.100).aspx